# How to find common rows in two sets of query results?

Tags: c#, sqlite

Right now I have two string queries:

`SELECT * FROM hmdb WHERE shamsidate MATCH '1376/05/24 1385/11/12'`

and,

`SELECT * FROM hmdb WHERE hmdb  MATCH 'content:red  OR keyword:red  v_other:true'`

and this is the way I show the results of each one:

```
            public void searchRecords()
            {
            SQLiteConnection m_dbConnection;
            m_dbConnection = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=hmdb.sqlite;version=3;");

            try
            {
                m_dbConnection.Open();
                SQLiteDataAdapter db = new SQLiteDataAdapter(queryString, m_dbConnection);
                DataTable dt = new DataTable("hmdb");
                db.Fill(dt);
                listView1.ItemsSource = dt.DefaultView;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                string ex = e.ToString();
                System.Windows.MessageBox.Show(ex);
            }
            finally
            {
                if (m_dbConnection != null)
                {
                    m_dbConnection.Close();
                    m_dbConnection.Dispose();
                }

            }
        }
```

Now, I wanted to know how can I get the common rows in both of these queries in order to show them in my listView; or better yet, is there a way to do just one query and get the desired result?

Comment: By Common rows you mean only common to both queries? Then use an `AND`. If you mean display common rows in both queries along with rows that query 1 matches alone and query 2 matches alone - use `UNION`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're looking for:

```
SELECT * FROM hmdb WHERE shamsidate MATCH '1376/05/24 1385/11/12'
INTERSECT
SELECT * FROM hmdb WHERE hmdb MATCH 'content:red OR keyword:red v_other:true'
```

The INTERSECT keyword is explained [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188055%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

Comment: doesn't give any results(no error either); it should return 3 results!

Comment: Can you show the data in your database. What does each query return?

Comment: actually the INTERSECT link perfectly described the answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You have two queries:

```
SELECT * FROM hmdb WHERE shamsidate MATCH '1376/05/24 1385/11/12'
SELECT * FROM hmdb WHERE hmdb MATCH 'content:red OR keyword:red v_other:true'
```

Just combine the where conditions and use one query instead using an `AND` clause (and parentheses to keep the logic consistent):

```
SELECT * FROM hmdb 
WHERE shamsidate MATCH '1376/05/24 1385/11/12' 
      AND (hmdb MATCH 'content:red OR keyword:red v_other:true')
```

Answer (score 0):

I think best would be to have `and` condition in the queries.

`SELECT * FROM hmdb WHERE shamsidate MATCH '1376/05/24 1385/11/12' and hmdb MATCH 'content:red OR keyword:red v_other:true'`

**Had it been two different tables, you could have used `Joins`.**

Comment: Do individual queries produce results?

Comment: I'm very sorry, but there is problem in my question; my first query should've been SELECT * FROM hmdb WHERE shamsidate MATCH '1376/04/22' UNION  SELECT * FROM hmdb WHERE shamsidate MATCH '1376/04/21'
should I post a new question or edit this one?

Comment: Then you first query should be `SELECT * FROM hmdb WHERE shamsidate MATCH '1376/04/22' and shamsidate MATCH '1376/04/21'`

Answer (score 0):

If By Common rows you mean only common to both queries? Then use an AND.

```
SELECT * FROM hmdb WHERE shamsidate MATCH '1376/05/24 1385/11/12'
AND (hmdb MATCH 'content:red OR keyword:red v_other:true')
```

If you mean display common rows in both queries along with rows that query 1 matches alone and query 2 matches alone - use UNION –

```
SELECT * FROM hmdb WHERE shamsidate MATCH '1376/05/24 1385/11/12'
UNION
SELECT * FROM hmdb WHERE hmdb MATCH 'content:red OR keyword:red v_other:true'
```